# Mac Eclipse instead of Windows IBM WebSphere Commerce Developer - Can it be done?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce

Im currently working as a frontend dev on WebSphere Commerce project. Currently for development I run WSC Developer in a Win7 VM. What i would like to do is get everything set up in the FOSS version of Eclipse (Helios or Indigo) on my Mac instead of using the WSC Developer app from IBM.

All DB's are shared and no network resources as opposed to local so a lack of DB2 or Oracle on my box shouldn't be an issue. My main concern is how to run the local testing server, and how to get all the basics set up. I know my way around Eclipse pretty well but not when it comes to Java development (I normally use PDT for PHP development).

Is it possible to do this, and keep everything but the DB's local and native? Or am I stuck with using the windows based toolkit?

Answer (score 3):

See

- [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php),
- [Installing WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/t_install_wdt.html),
- [Install and configure WebSphere Application Server on UNIX and Linux systems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-wasonlinux/section2.html)
   as well as
- [IBM developerworks Forum thread about installing WAS CE onto MacOSX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=119101).

In brief, Eclipse has full support for WAS and is platform-agnostic. WAS can be installed onto OSX all right with only a few custom steps to allow for OSX FS hierarchy differences, though it's not an officially supported setup.

[Set up Eclipse to work with Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775341/set-up-eclipse-to-work-with-java-ee) question may be useful to configure integration for a project.

Comment: Wrong product.  They're talking about WebSphere Commerce Developer.  Also generally speaking, even if they were talking about RAD, it's an heavily modified version of Eclipse and you can't use it with vanilla Eclipse.

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong: Actually we are using RAD on the Windows side... So maybe i got the names of the software packages incorrect? The key is though i wanted to be able to run a complete dev server (sans db) locally instead of using RAD in a Windows VM. I honestly dont need all the custom features. Just need to run the server. Even if that means i set it up completey outside eclipse and manually start/stop/bounce it from the CLI when needed.

Comment: Okay... If you're using RAD for Windows or Websphere Commerce Developer for Windows, you can use configure it to connect to a remote server.   It's part of the server environment setup wizards.  I wouldn't try to glue a vanilla eclipse on your Mac to WebSphere Commerce Server.  You're going to have to do a bunch of unsupported configurations to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are pretty much stuck with the windows platform for any WCS development. WebSphere Commerce is tightly coupled with WebSphere Application Server and you cannot run WCS on any other application server.

If you are planning to use eclipse for your development, you will end up putting your changed files to a test server outside of your mac envronment which is a nightmare in my opinion.

Comment: That wouldnt be a nightmare. We test locally commit to SVN. SVN is built to a development server every few hours. We verify our changes work correctly in that environment. Then a couple ours later SVN builds to a test environment (which is a 1:1 mirror of production) then we verify there. So the only thing that cahnges for me really is being able to work natively.

Comment: I don't think you got the comment.   WebSphere Commerce Developer only runs on Rational Application Developer which only runs on Windows.